# convert nsmanganedobject to array to find sum of array

Tags: arrays, core-data, swift4, nsmanagedobject

My code below is trying to take core data from a `NSManagedObject` append it to an array. The core data element is saved as a string. My code is not compelling. Ideally the code should be able to append code into the array then the array is filled, find the sum of the numbers added together and print them into the `viewDidLoad()` func.

```
var itemName : [NSManagedObject] = []

       func performAction() {
        let appD = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

        let context = appD.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Data")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        do {
            let result = try context.fetch(request)
            var retrievedData = [Double]()
            for data in result as! [NSManagedObject] {
                if let value = data.value(forKey: "ee") as? Double {
                    retrievedData.append(value)
                }
            }

            let arraySum = retrievedData.reduce(0, +)
            print(arraySum)

        } catch {

            print("Failed")
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Never use `Any`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reviewed your code when you will need to change small thing over there. Replace performAction function as per my updated answer.

```
 func performAction() {
        let appD = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

        let context = appD.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Data")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        do {
            let result = try context.fetch(request)
            var retrievedData = [Double]()
            for data in result as! [NSManagedObject] {
                if let value = data.value(forKey: "ee") as? String {
                    retrievedData.append(Double(value) ?? 0)
                }
            }

            let arraySum = retrievedData.reduce(0, +)
            print(arraySum)

        } catch {

            print("Failed")
        }
    }
```

Comment: This does not work it has multiple compiling errors.

Comment: I also dont know (entityName: "Stack") how you came up with.

Comment: put "Data" instead of "Stack"

Comment: I tried check out of the picture I added above with the errors. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Getting close after adding your code and some other code I prior had I can get the code to run and save the problem is the code is always zero. The arraySum does not increasing when more code is added to. I added a pic of my core data file above as well. Thanks.

Comment: if it is possible please share your project demo so i can help you

Comment: OK I uploaded my code to dropbox https://www.dropbox.com/s/ncmoojb4sottgm5/droper.zip?dl=0. Let me know if you can download very basic 2 view controllers.